# What's the typical directory usage for a home server?

Tags: linux, home-server

I am setting up a Linux home server with FTP/Web/NFS/SSH/GIT services. It will be used as a backup server.

What's the typical usage of directories to keep my system organized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything goes under [`/srv`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM), but...

> The methodology used to name subdirectories of `/srv` is unspecified as there is currently no consensus on how this should be done.

The home directory is of course useful if there's only one user that will use it.

Comment: though practically web serving comes under /var/www as well

Comment: Thanks. I will be the only user/admin. And my own configuration files are intended to go under `$HOME`. What's your suggestion for FTP files and git repository on the server?  Should be be under `/media/` directory as there are sort of external comparing to other files

Comment: @yangchenyun: What does the page I linked to say?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams sorry, just realized there is link there.